# Unwanted output in nested while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

My prompt: "Write a program that uses two nested while loops to print off the rows and columns of a 3x3 grid (numbered 1 to 3), excluding the cells along the diagonal (i.e., where the row and column have the same value).
The first three rows of your program's output should look like this:

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
```

I have coded it pretty well so far, but I am stuck with one extra unwanted output. How do I remove it?

```py
row = 0
while row < 3:
    col = 0
    row += 1
    while col < 3:
        col += 1
        if row == col:
            col += 1
        print (row, col)
```

expected result should be:

```
  1 2  
  1 3
  2 1
  2 3
  3 1
  3 2
```

but 3 4 is included as well.

Comment: Could you clarify what your input is? What I'm imagining this 3x3 grid to look like doesn't square with your expected output.

Comment: @nmpauls Hey, thanks for replying! I just want the coordinates as described in the post; minus the diagonals i.e 1 2, 1 3, 2 1, 2 3, 3 1, 3 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because where `row` and `col` both equals to 3, you are increasing `col` to 4, and print. Modify to:

```
row = 0
while row < 3:
    col = 0
    row += 1
    while col < 3:
        col += 1
        if row != col:
            print (row, col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition should change to print `(i, j)` only if they are not equal.

```
i = 1 
while i < 4:
    j = 1
    while j < 4:
        if i != j:
            print(i, j)
        j += 1
    i += 1
# 1 2
# 1 3
# 2 1
# 2 3
# 3 1
# 3 2
```

Also I've started iteration from 1 instead of 0 because this looks a little better organised to me.

P.S., the more idiomatic way of doing this would be using a list comprehension.

```
[(i, j) for i in range(1, 4) for j in range(1, 4) if i != j]
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you @cs95 I will definitely try this format as well!